# Single SQL statement to output lines from different tables

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to create a report. The report has to be in a specific format where I have one line from one table, then output corresponding data from another, then another line from the first table. Please see my example below:

**Person** table:

```
pid |   lname | fname
---------------------
1       Smith   John
2       Jones   Doe
```

**salary_history**:

```
pid |   salary
1       500000
1       550000
1       570000
2       400000
2       450000
```

Desired output:

```
1       Smith   John
1       500000
1       550000
1       570000
2       Jones   Doe
2       400000
2       450000
```

Each line in the output is a concatenation of each value. So for line 1 and line 2, it would be

```
person.pid + space(3) + person.lname + space(3) + person.fname + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + salary_hisory.pid + space(3) + salary_history.salary
```

Each person table entry could have hundreds of corresponding salary history entries. And there could be thousands of person entries.

I can do this by writing a T-SQL statement and loop, but it's probably inefficient and would take a lot of resources/time. Is it possible to do this in a single statement? Or is writing a loop my best option?

Comment: Is that output 1 row, with carriage returns and line breaks (as your pseudo code infers), or 6 rows?

Comment: What are you using to display this "report"? Are you using reporting software of any kind, or are you writing it out using HTML, Excel, or something other than that? Depending on how you are writing your report the answers could be drastically different, not to mention there being various ways to improve what you are trying to do (namely, getting rid of concatination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `unpivot` using `apply` :

```
select distinct p.pid, pp.*
from person p inner join
     salary_history sh
     on sh.pid = p.pid cross apply
     ( values (lname, fname), (cast(salary as varchar(255)), null) 
     ) pp(lname, fname)
order by p.pid, pp.lname desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  1 AS ReportGroup,
        pid,
        lname + '   ' + fname AS ReportValue
FROM    person
UNION
SELECT  2,
        pid,
        CAST(salary AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM    salary_history
ORDER BY ReportGroup, pid
```

Comment: Strongly recommend `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, in this case. Duplicates between the sets are impossible so why add an implicit distinct operation to the concat?